# Check for any down-stream data blocks

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

Is there a way to figure out whether `BroadcastBlock<T,T>` links to any data blocks?

How to check whether any down-stream data blocks are linked to from BroadcastBlock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There isn't. Dataflow blocks do not publicly expose linked blocks.